# Linear mixed model: Does the effect size of an interaction depend on the size of the main effects when size of interaction is kept constant?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, simulation, effect-size, statistical-power

Please also see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802229/how-to-interpret-effect-sizes-in-simr-power-simulation-for-mixed-models) where I describe how I stumbled upon this problem and where I show the respective R-Code.

I am running a power simulation where I specify the fixed effects for each predictor and their interaction, the random effects, and the residual variance of my model.

I calculate an effect size for the interaction term using this formula:
$f^2 = \frac{R_{full} - R_{reduced}}{1 - R_{full}}$

When keeping everything else constant, should the fixed effects for a single predictor affect the effect size f² for my interaction term? This is what I find in my simulations and I am uncertain whether this can be correct.

Comment: You can't keep things constant when they are involved in an interaction. If you change $x$ it is impossible to keep the interaction $xz$ contant.

Comment: So a $\beta_{a:b} = 0.5$ with $\beta_a = 0.1$ indicates a different effect size $f^2$ than with $\beta_a = 0.7$, given everything else being equal (same sample size, same scaling, same number of observations, same icc, etc.)?

Comment: I'm not really sure tbh. I always think of effect sizes as the coefficient estimate. $f^2$ isn't something I'm familiar with. If you simulate the data yourself you can set such effect sizes as you see fit.